# Accessing Child Node Firebase Realtime Database Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase

I'm trying to access all Chocolate Cake of all Data at once.

Any one let me know how to access these child.

Thanks in advance

Here is the image of database

[image]

I'm trying to access all Chocolate Cake of all Data at once.

Answer (score 1):

```
let chocolateCakeRef = Database.database().reference().child("MenuFoodItems/desserts/Cakes/Chocolate Cake")
chocolateCakeRef.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let cake = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let picURL = cake["picUrl"] as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend leaving firebase snapshots, 'snapshotty' so this will also work to access the picURL in code. `let url = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "picUrl").value as? String ?? ""`  - be careful force unwrapping optionals as this `as! String` will crash if it doesn't exist (nil).